Ext.js uncheck grid header button and refresh grid after panel load
I am currently working with a grid view panel. The grid has a header with a button to select or deselect all records of the view. By default all lines are selected. I would like to simulate the click on the header, after the page is loaded, to deselect all lines.
I tried to use selectionModel but I can’t refresh the view. If I do a grid.getStore().reload(), the Gris is empty… (whether I have deselected with selectionModel or not)
I’m using a customization that extends custom.AbstractExtensibleFramework
Any tips on how to do this grid update ?
Thank you all ahead for your help !
Best regards

could you setup a fiddle, so that it is easier to see how you did the setup? Otherwise you could add your view and controller in the question.

Hello ! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can’t share the code here. And I should have mentioned that I’m using customized extensible.

You can use the toggleAll method:
items: [{
     xtype: 'button',
     docked: 'bottom',
     text: 'toggle',
     handler: function() {
         // get the grid and the check column
         const grid = Ext.first('grid'),
               column = grid.getColumns()[0];
                    
         column.toggleAll();
     }           
}]

You can check the state before:
if (column.areAllChecked()) {
    // toggle only if all columns are checked
    column.toggleAll();
}


Hello ! Thank you very much for your answer. I’ll try it as soon as I get back from vacation !
